# Why after deploying static content I'm receiving 404 to merged css?

Tags: magento2, cache, 404, merge-css

I'm using Magento 2.3.3, after deploying some category pages are getting the wrong css, returning 404, I tried flushing the cache but it didn't work.

[image: Magento2 static content css 404]

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happening because the HTML has been cached by Varnish, so the browser was getting the old version getting the wrong CSS path.

You can access you host panel and **flush the Varnish** there, or you can run this command below if you have access.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/varnish restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, you didn't remove the _cache folder. Please try to remove everything in the pub/static/ except the htacess. And deploy.

Comment: It doesn't make sense since we don't need to remove the _cache folder manually to deploy static files, but even removing it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

just delete everything from pub->static->frontend folder and flush cache. 
hope this will solve your issue.